# Ubuntu 17.10.1 running slowly on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, 17.10, virtualization

I have installed 17.10.1 on VirtualBox but the UI is very slow. I have installed guest additions, turned up the VRAM, and turned on 3D acceleration. I don't know what to do next, would VMWare be any better?

Comment: @dsstorefile Yes, I do.

Comment: Set your VM to use 2 CPU's and 2048 system RAM, and you should be fine.

Comment: @heynnema I have 4GB of RAM set and 2 CPU's set already